# Show that the function is continuous and it has period 1

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

The function is defined on $\Bbb{C}\setminus\Bbb{Z}$ by $g(z)=\frac{1}{z}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2z}{z^2-n^2}$ . I think we have to start by expressing g as $g(z)= lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=-N}^{N} \dfrac{1}{z-n} $. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: You ragged this as real analysis... Are you sure you don't want to use techniques available from complex analysis? This seems strongly suited towards a use of the residue theorem.

Comment: I'm not sure,is there a way to do it through real analysis?